# Sorting on chaining query using laravel datatables server side function

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, datatables, yajra-datatable

I'm trying to sorting the column named **agency_name**. But its not working. The **full_name** is perfectly working while the **agency_name** column is not working. So basically I trying to access the data which in the **user_work_experiences** table, so the way I access them is through user table and get current user work experiences. Im using [yajra/datatables](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables) package. So here my table structure looks: -

Student Hostels

- user_id

Users:

- id

User Work Experiences

- user_id
- agency_name

**Here the example code:**

Controller:

```
public function getHostels()
{
    $hostels = StudentHostel::with('user', 'user.userProfile', 'user.currentWorkExperience', 'status')->limit(100)->select('student_hostels.*');

    return Datatables::of($hostels)
        ->addIndexColumn()
        ->editColumn('user.full_name', function (StudentHostel $hostel) {
            return $hostel->user->full_name;
        })
        ->editColumn('user.userProfile.address_1', function(StudentHostel $hostel) {
            return $hostel->user->userProfile ? $hostel->user->userProfile->address_1 . " " . $hostel->user->userProfile->address_2 : null;
        })
        ->addColumn('action', 'backEnd.hostel.datatables_action')
        ->orderColumn('user.full_name', function ($query, $order) {
            $query->whereHas('user', function ($q) use($order) {
               $q->orderBy('full_name', $order);
            });
        })
        ->orderColumn('user.current_work_experience.agency_name', function ($query, $order) {
            $query->whereHas('user', function ($q) use ($order) {
                $q->whereHas('currentWorkExperience', function ($q) use ($order) {
                    $q->orderBy('agency_name', $order);
                });
            });
        })
        ->orderByNullsLast()
        ->make(true);
}
```

Views:

```
$('#hostel_datatable').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: "{{ route('hostel.application.list') }}",
    columns: [
        {data: 'DT_RowIndex', name: 'DT_RowIndex', orderable: false, searchable: false},
        {data: 'user.full_name', name: 'user.full_name'},
        {data: 'user.current_work_experience.agency_name', name: 'user.current_work_experience.agency_name'},
        {data: 'user.userProfile.address_1', name: 'user.userProfile.address_1', orderable: false, searchable: false},
        {data: 'status.base_setup_name', name: 'status.base_setup_name', orderable: false, searchable: false},
        {
            data: 'action',
            name: 'action',
            orderable: true,
            searchable: true
        },
    ]
});
```

I hope you guys can help me out. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Got an answer yet? Got the same problem!

Comment: @NickAudenaerde not yet. I move on using basic pagination. I think for datatables better use query builder instead of eloquent